# What does 'as' mean when followed by v-ing?

Tags: meaning

I need help in fully comprehending the sentence below. Please take a look and thanks in advance. :)

*-From [a passage about Semiotics](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cBZCOD8SVzMC&pg=PA18&dq=%22Various%20typologies%20of%20signs%20have%20been%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Various%20typologies%20of%20signs%20have%20been%22&f=false)*

"Various typologies of signs have been proposed, but three fundamental classes of signs seem to stand out as requiring different approaches: the icon, the index, and the sign proper."

What does 'as requiring different approaches' mean? I can understand the sentence only up to the point where it says 'but three..stand out'.

1. What is requiring what?
2. Can I replace 'as requiring' to 'which requires'? If not, how can I say this confusing part differently?
3. Is as + v-ing certain usage of 'as'?

Comment: What is the source of your sentence? Can you post a link or picture?

Answer (score 1):

The more interesting phrase here is "[In the context of Ns], N stands out as A", where N is a noun that is part of Ns, and A is an adjective or adjective-like phrase.  Here are some examples:

- [In the history of ethics Bentham stands out as one of the ablest champions of utilitarianism.](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Dictionary_of_National_Biography_volume_04.djvu/282)
- [The year 1880 stands out as one of manifold misfortune and disaster to agricultural Russia.](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Popular_Science_Monthly_Volume_53.djvu/372)
- [You want to stand out as the best applicant the hiring committee has ever seen.](https://www.themuse.com/advice/35-surefire-ways-to-stand-out-during-your-job-search)
- [Some of the great fairy tales stand out as answering to this test.](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:A_Study_of_Fairy_Tales.djvu/63)

The phrase indicates that N is particularly A in the context.  In your example:

1. What requires what?  The "classes...require...approaches".
2. If you replace 'as requiring' with 'which require', it would imply that they really "stand out" more.  A different phrasing closer to the original meaning might be "there seem to be three fundamental classes that clearly require different approaches".
3. as+v-ing is not a fruitful analysis in this case, both because "as" is part of the phrase "stands out as", and because "requiring different approaches" is [adjective-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attributive_verb).

Comment: +1) I think your answer makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

To "stand out as requiring X" means to stand out because of the fact that they require X.

In your sentence: the icon, the index, and the sign proper stand out among fundamental classes of signs because they require different approaches.

No, you can't replace "as requiring" by "which requires". Replacing it by "because they require" would be closer to the mark.

Comment: I don't think "as" in the sentence has anything to do with "because".

Comment: @Rathony I never said it did! Just that "because they require" would be a reasonable(ish) paraphrase.

Comment: Let me rephrase my comment. I don't think "as requiring X" in the sentence has anything to do with "because of the fact that they require X"

Comment: @Rathony How about "in that they require X" - would you agree with that as a paraphrase?

Comment: "As" can mean a few things and I think "because of..." doesn't fit in the context. I just posted a comment to ask about the source. It is always better to clarify its source first and post an answer.

Comment: @Rathony: I think rand here is right on the money. The construction *X stands out **as** [being / needing / having] Y* always implies that if X *wasn't* (or *didn't need / have*) Y it wouldn't stand out. If replaced by ***which***, that same implication *might* be present, but not necessarily.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't agree. As could be used to indicate that something happens during the time when something else is taking place. They could be happening at the same time. Not just Y is causing X. That's why I needed more context.

Comment: @Rathony: I have actually edited the question to include *full* context, but I really don't see that we need anything more than the sentence as cited, in this particular case. Can you seriously propose an alternative surrounding context where it would be possible to replace ***as*** by ***while**?* I don't think even the most contrived context could justify that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't understand why you think Y should be a factor/reason for X to stand out. X can stand out while Y appearing or Y is just a relative clause (adjective) to relate to three fundamental classes. Do you mean I don't make any sense at all?

Comment: @Rathony: I mean ***as*** can have various different meanings. In the contexts of *X standing out **as** Y*, it's being used to introduce something *(Y)* expanding on the *way* (or *reason*) that *X* stands out. Consider the two possible interpretations of, say, ***As** a child, I traveled on the bus for half-fare*, where ***as*** can mean either ***when** [I was]* or ***because** [I was]*. The same two alternatives could apply to *I stood out **as** a child*, but only the latter makes sense in, say, *I stood out as being undernourished* (which matches OP's context).

Comment: Hi all, thanks so much for all these helpful information. Rephrasing really helped me to get the sense of what the sentence was trying to say. The passage came from GRE verbal workbook. I don't  know if a bit longer excerpt can help, but let me just try.
"Semiotics is based on the assumption that insofar as human actions or productions convey meaning,  insofar as they function as signs, there must be an underlying system of conventions and distinctions which makes this meaning possible. Where there are signs there is system. This is what various signifying activities have in common,

Comment: and if one is to determine their essential nature one must treat them not in isolation but as examples of semiotic systems.
(Paragraph changes)
*Various typologies...the icon, the index, and the sign proper.* All signs consist of a signifier and a signified, a form and an associated meaning or meanings; but the relations between signifier and signified are different for each of these three types of sign. An 'icon' involves blah blah blah. In an 'index' blah blah. In the 'sign' proper blah blah.

Comment: @user148466: Given that the surrounding context already uses ***insofar as*** twice, I suppose it would be stylistically weak to use it yet again. But in principle your target sentence could have read *...seem to stand out **insofar/in as much as** they require different approaches*. But rand here may be overstating the case in saying ***which require*** (note: not ***requires***, since there are *three* of them) is not a valid replacement. Pragmatically one would have to assume an implied ***because** they require*, since there's no other obvious reason why they would "stand out" at all.